# Custom Environmental Settings

Tags: config, multi-environment, environmentvariables

Is it possible to use custom environmental settings with Craft?

I have separate web services that I use in production and development environments. I would like to programmatically point to the appropriate service based on my environment. If I am in development, I should always point to the dev service...production...to the production service.

The [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#environmentVariables) leads me to believe that I can only use the settings that Craft provides.

How can I use custom environmental settings within Craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's absolutely possible, and available out of the box with craft.

In your `public/index.php` file you specify the different environments based on your server name.

With the environment set, inside your `craft/config/db.php` and `craft/config/general.php` files, you can create different configurations for each environment.

This article in the craft documentation goes over how to configure it. Let me know if you have any trouble, it's really just modifying those three files.

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs

Comment: To add to this nice answer: you can set up a custom setting (e.g. "myCustomSetting") just like you do default / core settings and then access it from the template with `craft.config.myCustomSetting`.

Comment: Oh, and there's no need to have them under "environmentVariables" (just noticed that the OP linked to this).

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you both Bryant and @carlcs for taking the time to answer such simple question. Kind of embarrassed with how simple the solution was. I think I need to unplug. Thanks again!